# How to open JavaScript link in a new tab using Selenium Python?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am new with Selenium and JavaScript. I am working on a web scraping project and need to scrape phone numbers of each 200 houses in each sector from http://propertytax.mcmohali.org/. After entering sector and house number, the site shows  a table. There is a "Select" link in the table which on checking with inspect element shows

> javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder2$grdSearchdetail','Select$0')

How can I open this in a new tab? When I open this link with a loop and then try to open another link by changing "Select$0" to "Select$1" in the above link. It gives Stale Element Error.

How can I open this JavaScript link in new tab and scrape data from it and then close it? Then go to the next "Select" link and scrape details in that?

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\aryan\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
time.sleep(5)
for i in range(9,11):
    for j in range(1,201):
        try:
            now = datetime.now()
            select_search(i,j,driver)
            df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_html(driver.page_source)[2])
#             df = get_phone(driver,df
            numlist=[]
            for num in range(df.shape[0]):
                select_search(i,j,driver)
                ele = driver.find_elements_by_link_text("Select")
                ele[num].click()
                number = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ContentPlaceHolder2_txtOwnerMobileNo']").get_attribute("value")
                numlist.append(number)
            df["Phone No"] = numlist    
            data = data.append(df,ignore_index=True)
            print("Time taken for house no. ",str(j)," : ",datetime.now()-now)
#             if j%50 ==0:
#                 flag1 = input("Continue to next 50 listings? [y/n]: ")
#                 if flag1.lower() == "y":
#                     print("Going to next 50 house numbers!!!")   
#                     continue
#                 else:
#                     break
        except:
            print("** ERROR in HOUSE NO : ",j)
            continue
    data.to_excel(str(i)+".xlsx",index = False)
    flag2 = input("Continue to next sector? [y/n]: ")
    if flag2.lower() == "y":
        print("Going to next sector!!!")   
        continue
    else:
        break
```

Comment: you don't really need to.  There's no benefit to opening this in a new tab/window.  Just click it as you normally would, do your stuff, and navigate from there.  To avoid stale element, re-grab your elements.

Comment: It strikes me as odd that there is so much personal data available on this website, especially if that contains telephone numbers. Does your country require you to respect some data protection principles when doing this?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.